# Use @IBInspectable with any UIView subclass within storyboards

Tags: swift, generics, xcode-storyboard, ibinspectable

I have a class to use with `@IBInspectable`, to get the properties within my storyboard. Here is a small chunk of it:

```
/// UIView subclass to allow creating corners, shadows, and borders in storyboards.
final class GEView: UIView {

    // MARK: - Rounded corners
    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

This works completely fine within `UIView`s in my storyboard. However, I want this to also work with `UIImageView`s and other subclasses of `UIView`. Is this possible without subclassing my `GEView`, by somehow making this a generic?

Comment: you can define an extension on `UIView`. However, the simplest solution is usually to wrap `UIImageView` in your custom view.

Comment: @Sulthan I'm just surprised there isn't some generic way to do this...

Comment: `UIView` are old. Designables are still rather new. The whole concept is far more difficult than you think.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks, I have now done that instead! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your code to UIView's `@IBDesignable extension` like below:

```
@IBDesignable extension UIView {    
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
        get {
            return self.cornerRadius
        }
    }
}
```

Clear unwanted values/types of previously deifned vars in your `GEView`. Here are values in inspector.

[image]

Properties available in inspector of any UIView, included itself.

[image: Properties avaliable in storyboard interface]

Comment: wait plz. I try to got it

Comment: You can set default on storyboard. no need to set right here. Remove any `@IBInspectable var` in subclasses of `UIView`. Did it helped?

Comment: Try to clear some values in User Defined Runtime Attributes on Identify Inspector in Storyboard. Some incorrect values can be stored there

Comment: Ok, this is super weird. Now anything but `UIView`s are useable in storyboard 

Comment: There is some `User Defined Runtime Attributes` for `GEView` which are `UIView`s, but don't show up in the inspector pane.

Comment: I use this code in my project and works very well. Seems to be you have some incorrectly overrided values...

Comment: I'm not getting any properties to see and change in storyboards for `UIView`s  I'm just going to stick with what *@Sulthan* said of wrapping them in `UIView` - however this complicates the hierarchy, so if this can be made to work, it would be better.

Comment: Oh wait no... my stupid self of not realising it says `newValue` in your code... 

Comment: I only get the default properties such as `Content Mode` and such, and I have made sure that the class is set to `GEView`.

Comment: How/Where you want to get the properties?

Comment: I have properties available in `UIView` subclasses, yay! However, I'm no longer getting them for `UIView` itself.

Comment: I don't understand you. All you need are reachable. I updated an answer

Comment: Once again, my dumb self... I still had my `UIView` as a `GEView` - I should have removed it

Comment: Also, just quickly, how do I stop this function calling itself? (https://imgur.com/dlzYZhU) Thanks!

Comment: Change set to willSet, remove get {}. If you create new question – I could answer with code)

Comment: I am not using this `extension` method as I want shadows, which are not possible with `extensions`. I will use my class as before where all views to be rounded were encapsulated by a `UIView` set to a `GEView`. However, as this did answer my initial question, I will still accept it as the answer.